# Can I pass parameters to a content slot from the calling ISML?

Tags: demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I'd like to be able to pass some supplementary information to a Content Slot, either through a request scope variable or some other means.

I've tried this in my calling ISML:

```
<isset name="message" scope="request" value="I want to be an Air Force Ranger" />
<isslot id="slot-message" context="global" description="banner"/>
```

And in the rendering template for the slot I have:

```
<iscontent type="text/html" charset="UTF-8" compact="true"/>
<iscache type="relative" hour="24"/>
<h3>${request.custom.message}</h3>
```

However, in the output HTML, I just get:

```
<h3>null</h3>
```

Is there some way I can pass an Object or String to a Content Slot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content asset don't have access to the data created or passed to ISML. However, a workaround can be done by adding the data to the DOM and then reading it inside the content asset:

```
<div class="banner-data" data-message="${message}">
    <isslot id="slot-message" context="global" description="banner"/>
</div>
```

Then, in your content asset, you can read the message and use it:

```
<script>
    var bannerData = $('.banner-data').data();
    var message = bannerData["message"];
</script>
```

Comment: Clever! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Content Assets is not aware of the page they are embedded in. This is by design. You can however embed HTML inside your content by using $include()$ which fetches html from a named controller or link to another page on the site using any of the $url-methods.

In the Content Templates it is further possible to reference data from the contentslot or from the content itself using: ${slotcontent} and ${slotcontent.content} respectively.